# Model number for HP MDS600 drive caddies

Tags: hard-drive, hotswap

I am looking for the model number(s) for the hot swap Hard drive caddies that can be used with the HP MDS600 drive array.
I may then use these model numbers to purchase the caddies so I may attach several SATA drives that I already have with me.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2):

HP does not sell the caddies separately, just the drive kits. So they don't have their own part number. Your best bet would be buying them off [ebay](http://www.ebay.com). You can use any spare drive kit P/N from [MDS600 manual](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01728759/c01728759.pdf) + "(tray, sled, caddy, carrier, bracket)" for the search query.

Before buying any extra caddies I would recommend trying the drives you want to add to your storage with the caddies from your existing drives. I do not have first-hand experience with MDS600 but other StorageWorks systems I worked with would not accept any non-HP branded drives (i.e. the system checks drives' model numbers and rejects them if they are not on the approved list).